# getting individual parts from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this data coming from an api and I need to seperate date and time from string in javascript .

Here is the data
           dt_txt: "2019-02-03 12:00:00"

What i want is that a varible should should 2019-02-03 and another variable should hold 12:00:00.
How do i acheive this in javascript ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 
Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far. It will help to track the issue and get expert's help.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `split()` function which returns the individual parts of the original string separated by the given argument.

```
var [date, time] = dt_txt.split(' ');
```

---

Note that the variable assingment syntax is ES6 and may not work in some (old) browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** method of `string`

```js
let data = "2019-02-03 12:00:00".split(' ');
let first = data[0];
let second = data[1];
console.log(first)
console.log(second);
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @Martin Heralecký i could have done like you did but i didn't wanted to confuse this newbie

Comment: Of course, I'm not saying you have to use the new syntax. What I meant is that the `split` function is called twice in your example, which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Looks better now :), +1.

Answer (score 1):

Processing the raw string you can do something like this:

```js
const fullDateAsString = "2019-02-03 12:00:00"
const fields = fullDateAsString.split(" ")
console.log(fields[0])
console.log(fields[1])
```

You can however refer to [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in order to obtain a more fine grained access to date/time fields:

```js
const dateAndTimeAsString = "2019-02-03 12:00:00"
const dateAndTime = new Date(dateAndTimeAsString)
console.log(dateAndTime) // Caution: depending to the timezone configured on the browser's machine, single fields can be adjusted applying the timezone offset
console.log(dateAndTime.getFullYear())
console.log(dateAndTime.getMonth()) // 0 for Jan, 1 for Feb, ...
// etc
```